# Basic cURL form interaction

Tags: windows, forms, curl

Good afternoon -
  I have a business need to download a file located @ https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt.  Up until last month, this was a fairly simple routine.  In my automation tool, I used cURL to simply navigate to that URL and output the data.

However, the Fed recently changed functionality on this site so you are now redirected to https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/agreement.html where you need to 'Agree' to certain T&C.  I'm guessing that the 'Agreement' click and subsequent download can be accomplished via cURL but I'm not quite sure how to go about doing it.

Any advice? I'm attempting to achieve this using Automic Automation Engine running on Windows 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I'm not familiar with Automic Automation Engine, but I had the exact same issue when they changed the URL and put in the agreement check. I had to update my company's perl script to handle it.

If you're familiar with perl, you can use WWW::Mechanize to get past the agreement page pretty easily. I'm using Linux but the perl code should be the same on Windows I believe.

Here's the test script I wrote, $mech->content() will contain the contents of FedACHdir.txt. Here I have it just dumping the content into a text file of the same name. Then you can process the file with whatever else you need to.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $url = 'https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(autocheck => 1);
$mech->get($url);

if($mech->uri() ne $url) {
    $mech->form_name('acceptedForm');
    $mech->click_button(value => 'Agree');
}

#print ($mech->content());

my $filename = 'FedACHdir.txt';
$mech->save_content($filename);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem, solved it with 3 calls to cURL. Two things were key: store the session cookie in a file and resubmit to the agreement page, and the submitAgreement url ends with ".do"

NOTE: I had to replace ":" in the urls with [colon] because of a poor reputation (I'm posting as guest).

```
curl -c cookies1.txt https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt

curl --data "agreementValue=Agree" -b cookies1.txt https[colon]//www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/submitAgreement.do 

curl -b cookies1.txt https[colon]//www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt -o saveroutingnums.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

using curl for windows this .bat file worked:

```
curl.exe -c cookies1.txt https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt

curl.exe -s -d "agreementValue=Agree" -b cookies1.txt https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/submitAgreement 

curl.exe -b cookies1.txt https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt -o fedachdir.txt
```